# MySQL full text indexing via SQL not working

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I am using `MySQL 5.6+` which supports full text indexing. I want to build full-text indexing to several columns. When I have tried via `GUI` for full-text index it works fine. But `SQL` query not work. What I have tried is

```
ALTER TABLE `joom_content`
ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `introtext` (`introtext`);
```

This is not working. Showing 0 row affected. Whats wrong here?

> /* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 4.290 sec. */

Comment: Please see joomla 3.3.6 database. Trying to index `prefix_content` table 's two column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE  table_name  
ADD FULLTEXT(column_name1, column_name2,…)
```

Go to the tutorials:

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/activating-full-text-searching.aspx

```
 ALTER TABLE `TableName`
        ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `IndexName` (`ColumnName`);
```

Comment: yes tried. Nothing happened. Same error showing. I have tried for 1 column

Comment: ALTER TABLE `joom_content`
        ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `FullText` (`introtext`); tried this. Couldn't understand why not working